# Sharepoint Designer Approval tasks assigned to old domain account

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, user-profile, user-accounts, approval

We recently migrated from Windows domain A, to Windows domain B.

In our SharePoint Designer Workflow, we try to assign an approval task to a user which we lookup from another list, this user is the correct domain B account.

However, the approval task itself gets assigned to the domain A account of this user, and when the user tries to Approve he gets: Task update not accepted and the error in the workflow is: The user who attempted to complete the task is not the user to whom the task is assigned.

Any ideas on how to solve this, we do not have access to CA.

Comment: have all the users in the environment had a move-spuser applied? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607729.aspx

Comment: To be honest, I have no idea, as also said in the question, I'm not actual administrator of this SharePoint or Windows domain, and have no access to Central Administrator etc. We were hoping to find an easy solution before having to contact the administrators overseas

Comment: Have them use `Move-SPUser`, that is the official way of migrating users within SharePoint. This is going to be the easiest solution, otherwise you'll need to republish all of the workflows, reassign permissions on all of the sites they have access to, and so on.